# AlpineJS - How to add classes on the trigger button

Tags: alpine.js

I am using AlpineJS and I have this HTML:

```
<div x-data="{ open: false }" class="flex">
   <button type="button" @click="open = ! open" class="" aria-expanded="false">Women</button>


<div x-show="open" x-transition>
My hidden text
</div>
</div>
```

What it does is basically showing "My hidden text" when I press the button. So far so good. However I want to add classes to the button itself.

I tried this:

```
   <button type="button" @click="open = ! open" x-transition x-transition:enter="border-indigo-600 text-indigo-600" x-transition:leave="bordertransparent text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-800" class="" aria-expanded="false">Women</button>
```

But this does not add the classes `border-indigo-600 text-indigo-600` to the button itself.

Any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: not sure if you can use Alpine Transition for thing like Tailwind transition-colors ... but you could just bind the classes `x-bind:class="open?'border-indigo-600 text-indigo-600':'bordertransparent text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-800'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ... :class="open?'classes_when_open_is_true':'classes_when_open_is_false'" ... > ... </button>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer